# Is there an alternative to deserializing using setters and @JsonProperty for Spring

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, deserialization

Just using two very basic examples.. is there an alternative to deserializing JSON to a POJO where I don't need to create setters and where I don't need to declare @JsonProperty on each field?

@JsonProperty seems tedious and repetitive 
Setters seems to weaken encapsulation.

Using setters:

```
public class Person{
    private int age;
    private String name;

    public int getAge(){
        return age;
    }

    public void setAge(int age){
        this.age = age;
    }

    public String getName(){
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name){
        this.name = name;
    }
}
```

Using @JsonProperty:

```
public class Person{
    @JsonProperty private int age;
    @JsonProperty private String name;

    public int getAge(){
        return age;
    }

    public String getName(){
        return name;
    }
}
```

Comment: You can use `@JsonCreator` on the constructor, check these [examples](https://www.baeldung.com/jackson-annotations)

Comment: chrsblck, even if you use Jsoncreator, you have to use JsonProperty for custom field name.

Comment: The main reason why I ask this question is because at my last job, I created POJOs and it automatically deserialized without any annotations. It only required getters (which I needed anyway). I should have, but didn't, ask how that was accomplished.

Comment: @juice, as long as json field names and java class field names are same, you can serialize/desrialize easily without any jsonProperty.

Comment: I did that yesterday when I tried deserializing JSON into an object with two BigDecimal as fields and it would not work unless I had setters or annotated with @JsonProperty.

Comment: @Sambit The OP is asking for a way around using setters, which `@JsonCreator` is used for. IIRC, json creator only requires `@JsonProperty` when the field names do not match.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Jackson has the auto-detection feature which by default will only deserialise all **public** fields and all setters. That 's why if all of the fields are private , nothing will be deserialised if there are no setters.

You can use `@JsonAutoDetect` to configure this auto-detection feature such that it will deserialise even the fields are private. So in this way , you don't not need to add any setters anymore.

To configure per object :

```
@JsonAutoDetect(fieldVisibility = Visibility.ANY)
public class Person{
    private int age;
    private String name;
}
```

To configure globally such that you do not need to configure for each object:

```
ObjectMapper om = new ObjectMapper();
om.setVisibility(PropertyAccessor.FIELD, Visibility.ANY);
```

Comment: So I just need to instantiate an ObjectMapper class and invoke a method? Where would I put this code? In the Main method? Is there anyway to configure this in application.properties? I'm referring to the globally solution. Btw this is awesome.

Comment: Nevermind I figured it out. This was awesome. I just put `spring.jackson.visibility.field=ANY` in application.properties file

Answer (score 0):

An alternative is creating a Builder, in which the [only annotations that Jackson needs](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-databind/wiki/Databind-annotations) are `@JsonDeserialize` and `@JsonPOJOBuilder`, e.g:

```
@JsonDeserialize(builder = Person.Builder.class)
public class Person {
  ...
  @JsonPOJOBuilder(buildMethodName = "build", withPrefix = "")
  public static class Builder {
    ...
    public Builder age(final int age) {
      this.age = age;
      return this;
    }
    ...
  }
}
```

I believe it's as tedious as annotating each field with @JsonProperty, but in terms of immutability it's better than setters.

Answer (score 0):

For Getter/Setter try using Lombok, could refer this https://www.baeldung.com/intro-to-project-lombok.

Main goal of Lombok is to reduce boiler plate code and it is pretty much useful.

And about @JsonProperty, if you don't mark the attribute with the annotation the package will not know which should it serializer or deserialize.So no other go